# Perl code understanding

Tags: regex, perl

I am new to perl language - I have been trying to understand the below code

```
if ( $nextvalue !~ /^.+"[^ ]+ \/cs\/.+\sHTTP\/[1-9]\.[0-9]"|\/\/|\/Images\/fold\/1.jpg|\/busines|\/Type= OPTIONS|\/203.176.111.126/)
```

Can you please help us understand what is above meant for?

Comment: Not until you look at the preview before hitting the post button.

Comment: Hi, i just want to know what that if loop checking the condition

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whenever i am unsure what some cryptic regular expression does, i turn to Debuggex:

```
^.+"[^ ]+ \/cs\/.+\sHTTP\/[1-9]\.[0-9]"|\/\/|\/Images\/fold\/1.jpg|\/busines|\/Type= OPTIONS|\/203.176.111.126
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/a_CHQ3ypUg2w7ymL)

This is a railroad diagram, every string that has a substring fitting the description along any of the grey tracks will match your regex. As your condition uses `!~` meaning "does not match", those strings will then fail the check.
Debuggex certainly has issues (for example it displays `^`, meaning you would have to know that this means the beginning of the string, same for dots and other, whitespaces show up as underscroes, etc.) but it certainly helps in understanding the structure of the expression and possibly gives you an idea what the author had in mind.

Answer (score 2):

condition will be true when `$nextvalue` will *NOT* match following [regular expression](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html).

Regular expressiion will match if that string

- either

  - starts with at least one character,
  - followed by double quote sign (`"`),
  - followed by at least one non-whitespace character,
  - followed by whitespace (),
  - followed by string "/cs/",
  - followed by at least one character,
  - followed by whitespace and string HTTP/,
  - followed by one of digits from 1 to 9 inclusive,
  - followed by dot
  - followed by one of digits from 0 to 9,
  - followed by double quote mark (`"`)
- or contains two forward slashes (`//`)
- or contains sunstring "`/Images/fold/1.jpg`"
- or contains substring "`/busines`"
- or contains substring "`/Type= OPTIONS`"
- or contains substring "`/203.176.111.126`"

Comment: The last alternative is: `/203 any_char 176 any_char 111 any_char 126` (the dot is not escaped).

Comment: @JESUISCHARLIE Nitpicking your nitpicking: The same is true for the dot in "Images" path. ^^